# Sort clanwars by date, without showing before today

Tags: php, mysql, date, helper

I want to sort clanwars by date, without showing the clanwars that are before today (showing the clanwars of today too, ">="), but I don't know how, I'm using webspell (CMS) and don't know how to do it. This is the code:

```
$ergebnis=safe_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."clanwars ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0, ".$maxresults);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ergebnis=safe_query(
"SELECT *
FROM ".PREFIX."clanwars
WHERE `date` > DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 0, ".$maxresults);
```

`NOW()` returns the current date and time, `DATE()` returns just the date part, which is equivalent to `2013-09-12 00:00:00`.

Comment: Thank you, but don't work too, it show clanwars from 6th September, 9th etc. but I want that these clanwars where hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ergebnis=safe_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."clanwars WHERE date >= curdate() ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0, ".$maxresults);
```

Edit: convert date field to MySQL date format

```
$ergebnis=safe_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."clanwars WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') >= curdate() ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0, ".$maxresults);
```

Comment: I have clanwars at 6th September, 8th September etc. I don't want to show clanwars before today.

Comment: What type is your date column and what is the exact value of the dates you say fail? Are they "2013-09-06" and "2013-09-08"?

Comment: No, this is the code that set the date: $date=date("d.m.Y", $ds['date']); Its 06.09.2013. Its webspell so you can see how it works in Calendar.php http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/webspell/calendar.php, and see what I'm trying to change in http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/webspell/sc_results.php

Comment: Thank you again Vlad, but it not work. Now it shows the clanwars blank, so can see anything.

Comment: What is the column type of `date`?

Comment: I have used this code and it works. Thank you too much :). $ergebnis=safe_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."clanwars WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0, ".$maxresults);